# Why does the output of below query is work,one : 8 and work.two: 5?

Tags: sas

**Why does the output of below query is work,one : 8 and work.two: 5 ?**

```
DATA INPUT;
        INPUT VAR1 :$10. VAR2 :$10.;
         DATALINES;
         A one
         A two
         B three
         C four
         A five
         ;
         RUN;

data WORK.ONE WORK.TWO;
 set WORK.INPUT;
 if Var1='A' then output WORK.ONE;
 output;
run;
```

Comment: Two OUTPUT statements. Track each one, note that if no data set is specified it will write to both data sets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per the [SAS Documentation for the `OUTPUT` statement](https://documentation.sas.com/doc/en/pgmsascdc/9.4_3.5/lestmtsref/n1lltvbis7ye1an1eryo4leh2mck.htm):

> Without Arguments
>
> > Using OUTPUT without arguments causes the current observation to be written to all data sets that are named in the DATA statement.

So the final `output;` statement writes to all datasets specified on the `data` statement - in this case, both `one` and `two`.  The records with `A` will be written a second time based on the `if Var1='A' then output WORK.ONE;` line.